# Problem with Apply

Tags: functions

I have am trying to obtain the average of the distance from the mean radius for each shot in a group of shots at a target.  I am having problems with the very last line.  The output of the last line appears that the Apply statement is being applied to the correct level but it is not resolving.

code

```
ShotsPerGroup = 3  
NumberGroups = 2  
(* Define the group of shots as a random variable with a normal distribution *)  
RandomSeed[66936, Method -> All]  
R := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]];  
a = Flatten[
   Table[List[i, R], {i, 1, NumberGroups}, {j, 1, ShotsPerGroup}], 
   1];  
Print["a = ", TableForm[a]]  
(* Group the shots by group *)  
byGroup = GatherBy[a, First][[All, All, 2]];  
Print["byGroup =", byGroup]  
(* Calculate the distance from the mean radius of each shots by group *)  
mr = Sqrt[(#^2 + Mean[#]^2)] & /@ byGroup  
Print["mr = ", TableForm[mr]]  
(* obtain the mean of the group mean radius *)  
meanMR = 
 Apply[Mean, Sqrt[(#^2 + Mean[#]^2)] & /@ byGroup, 1]
```

output from last line:

> ```
> {Mean[1.1711, 0.717469, 0.980774], Mean[0.631837, 1.55101, 0.573568]}
> ```

Comment: The second argument of `Apply` matches `mr`. Why not just stick that in? You are also confusing the use cases of `Map` (short form - `/@`) and `Apply`. `meanMR = Mean /@ mr` returns `{1.64748, 1.13594}`.

Comment: i swear i tried that!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat more detailed answer, though this question *"arises due to a simple mistake..."*

`Mean` takes a list as its argument. What you had was `{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}`. The `FullForm` of this is:

```
List[List[a, b, c], List[d, e, f]]
```

`Apply` at level 1 replaces the heads of list at level 1 like so:

```
List[Mean[a, b, c], Mean[d, e, f]]
```

while what you needed, was:

```
List[Mean[List[a, b, c]], Mean[List[d, e, f]]]
```

which is exactly the result of *`Map`ping*.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer in detail.  That was very helpful!